# Find and remove the elements with the specific attribute in the cloned object using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to find and remove all the elements with specific attribute in the cloned object.

Following code works with the original object:

```
angular.element('.some-class [contenteditable]').removeAttr('contenteditable');
```

This code works fine, but don't know how to do it clone the object like:

```
temp = angular.element('.some-class').clone();
```

I want to remove all the elements with the attribute 'contenteditable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method, then perform the desired operation and use [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

```
temp = angular.element('.some-class')
    .clone()
    .find('[contenteditable]')
    .removeAttr('contenteditable')
    .end();
```